# how to distinguish which component called a callback function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react, sorry if that is newbe question. I have a component Dropdown which returns a value via a callback function. I would like to render that twice to choose two different values and then simply render chosen values below. How can I allow your two different components to send different data to the  component. Below is my code.

index.js

```
import { Dropdown } from './components/dropdown'

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.calculateRate = this.calculateRate.bind(this);
    this.callApi = this.callApi.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      response: "",
      currA: 0,
      currB: 1
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    this.callApi()
      .then(res => this.setState({ response: res.express }))
      .catch(err => {console.log(err)});

  }

  callApi = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('/main');
    const body = await response.json();
    if (response.status !== 200) throw Error(body.message);
    return body;
  }

  calculateRate = (key, val) => {
    // if the calling agent sent currA data, update currA,
    // else if the calling agent sent currB data, update currB
    if (key === 'A') this.setState({currA: val})
    if (key === 'B') this.setState({currB: val})
    console.log('updated curr' + key + ' to ' + val);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='App'>
        <div>
          <Dropdown callbackFromParent={this.calculateRate}
            stateKey={'A'} val={this.state.currA} />
          <Dropdown callbackFromParent={this.calculateRate}
            stateKey={'B'} val={this.state.currB} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default App;
```

dropdown.js

```
export class Dropdown extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      list: [],
      selected: ""
    };
  }

componentDidMount(){
  fetch('https://api.fixer.io/latest')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(myJson => {
      this.setState({ list: Object.keys(myJson.rates) });
    });
}

  render(){
    var selectCurr = (curr) =>
     <select
      onChange={event => props.callbackFromParent(props.stateKey, event.target.value)}
     >
     {(this.state.list).map(x => <option>{x}</option>)}
     </select>;

    return (
      <div>
        {selectCurr()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve, but hopefully the following shows how you can allow your two different components to send different data to the `<App>` component.

The important changes are: we need to bind methods to the `<App>` component in the `constructor()` function, then we can use the `.bind()` method in the `Dropdown` component to specify the data to pass into the callback function:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.calculateRate = this.calculateRate.bind(this);
    this.callApi = this.callApi.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      response: "",
      currA: 0,
      currB: 1
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    /*
    this.callApi()
      .then(res => this.setState({ response: res.express }))
      .catch(err => {console.log(err)});
    */
  }

  callApi = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('/main');
    const body = await response.json();
    if (response.status !== 200) throw Error(body.message);
    return body;
  }

  calculateRate = (key, val) => {
    // if the calling agent sent currA data, update currA,
    // else if the calling agent sent currB data, update currB
    if (key === 'A') this.setState({currA: val})
    if (key === 'B') this.setState({currB: val})
    console.log('updated curr' + key + ' to ' + val);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='App'>
        <div>
          <Dropdown callbackFromParent={this.calculateRate}
            stateKey={'A'} val={this.state.currA} />
          <Dropdown callbackFromParent={this.calculateRate}
            stateKey={'B'} val={this.state.currB} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Dropdown = props => (
  <select onChange={event => props.callbackFromParent(props.stateKey, event.target.value)}>
    <option value='cats'>Cats</option>
    <option value='dogs'>Dogs</option>
  </select>
)

export default App;
```

Comment: That is exactly what I need, still seems to not work though. I changed index.js as you showed here, in my dropdown.js component I did: <select onChange={event => this.props.callbackFromParent.bind(null, this.props.stateKey, event.target.value)} > and I added to render() method in index.js <p>
{this.state.currA} {this.state.currB} </p> to simply render new values. And I got no results. I cannot work it out...

Comment: @Malvinka I updated my answer to use a select. Because you create an anonymous function inside the `onChange` callback, you can just pass variables into the callback function without binding those variables. Also note that the Dropdown component accesses props with `props[propName]`, not `this.props[propName]` -- does the updated answer above help?